# Can't boot ACPI error

Tags: boot, acpi

My Dell Inspiron 5570 laptop has been working fine since I bought it 2 years ago. I've been running a dual boot setup with Windows 10 and Ubuntu (first 16.04, now 18.04) ever since.

Specifications:

- Dell Inspiron 5570
- 128gb SSD and 1 TB hard disk were already in the laptop
- One month ago replaced the DVD drive with a 1 TB Samsung 860 SSD
- Intel CPU i7
- 8 GB RAM

Unfortunately, my laptop started behaving strangely. Here's what happened:

1. I was doing some work on Windows when the operating suddenly froze. I was only able to shut it down with a hard reset.
2. I couldn't boot into Windows anymore after this happened. Each time it started doing disk checks and diagnostics, all these tests passed, but it still couldn't get into Windows.
3. I was still able to boot into Ubuntu, had to leave for the train and did some work there. When I arrived at my destination I put my laptop in sleep mode.
4. Back at home tried to start my laptop, literally nothing happened, it didn't even start. I thought maybe it was the battery, but even after plugging in my charger nothing happened. After 20 clicks and holding the power button for like 15 seconds it finally started booting.
5. Here's where everything collapsed. At this point I also couldn't boot into Ubuntu anymore. The errors I got were this:

Most of the times:

[image]

Sometimes:

[image]

6. I didn't do any updates whatsoever before this happened. The only change to my laptop was a new SSD which I installed one month ago, the Samsung 860 QVO 1TB 2,5 inch SSD which I placed in my DVD drive slot. Ubuntu and Windows were both booting from this disk. My old SSD was still in my laptop but was not in use, I'll refer to this disk as my 128gb native SSD. The laptop also includes a 1 TB hard disk that was already in the laptop when I bought it.
7. I removed my Samsung 860 SSD and tried booting from an Ubuntu 18.04 live USB. Same errors appeared. Also installing didn't work, with the same error.
8. I tried installing Windows 10 on my old 128gb native SSD which was already in the laptop, but this did work. Installing Ubuntu didn't work as I didn't even get to the install screen.
9. After some Googling I tried disabling ACPI. This allowed me to boot into the Ubuntu live USB and now I was also able to get to the install window.

Installing Ubuntu with `ACPI=off` on my 128gb SSD resulted in the following error:

[image]

- Installing Ubuntu with `ACPI=off` on my 1 TB hard disk worked, but everything is very slow, probably because `acpi=off` disables something with the graphics, but shutting down results in an infinite loop of the splash screen.
- Installing Ubuntu with `ACPI=off` on my new Samsung 860 SSD worked, but everything is very slow, probably because `acpi=off` disables something with the graphics, but shutting down results in an infinite loop of the splash screen.

**Other things I've done:**
- Latest BIOS update from Dell

- Dell extended diagnostics from BIOS which took 4 hours. All of the 
  tests passed.

**EDIT1:**

- dmesg dump: https://justpaste.it/6wa8d
- journalctl -b dump: https://justpaste.it/5l5h8

**EDIT2**

- Cleaned cpu fan, other parts were not dusty
- Starting from live usb doesn't work
- Reinstalled windows 10 again and removed all other partitions on all disks. Windows keeps freezing randomly

**EDIT3**
I'm pretty much out of options now. Would it be advisable to bring my laptop to a local computer repair shop?

**EDIT4**
Disconnected both SSD and wifi network adapter, Ubuntu 18.04 live usb gives same ACPI error. When adding kernel parameter acpi=off I can get into the Ubuntu environment. Added dmesg and journalctl -b logs of live usb:

- Dmesg: https://pastebin.com/W1WpxEmy
- journalctl -b https://pastebin.com/vhTJu0Kc

**EDIT5**
Current error booting from live USB

[image]

**EDIT6**
Tried Ubuntu 19.10

- With default kernel paramsz same acpi error as edit 5.
- with acpi=off, I get a kernel panic error. This is the same error as in step 9.

Error:
[image]

Comment: This is a hardware problem.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yeah probably. Do you know how I can find out what the hardware problem is? And how I could fix it?

Comment: Those boot messages are the second thing that I would check. The first thing that I would check is if you can see any error message when the computer is posting before grub starts to boot. If such a message exists it's typically just one line of white text on a black screen and it quickly disappears. If that line has anything to do with RAM then there's the culprit, a broken RAM stick. I the laptop has 2 or more RAM sticks it will be able to boot without the bad RAM stick plugged in.

Comment: As it all started in Windows I'm wondering if a system update there caused the problem? Specifically something tied to BIOS updates. You installed the latest BIOS update from DELL but I wonder if the version before that might work?

Comment: @karel Thanks for your response. There are no error messages before Grub loads.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Hmm I could try to install an older bios version.

Comment: @daveclarke My Dell's updates are over a year behind not just for BIOS but for a dozen other areas. On one hand it would be nice being up-to-date, OTOH *"If it ain't broke, don't fix it"*.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix Downgrading BIOS to a year ago also doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: @daveclarke I'm sorry to hear that. I've found Dell Support Forums to be helpful in the past.

Comment: I've reviewed the logs. There may be more than one problem here. In your testing, did you run a memory test? Do this... disconnect network and USB and external video devices/cables. Disconnect SATA data cables from all three drives, both SSD and HDD (or remove the drives). Try and boot to a Ubuntu Live USB. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I may miss them.

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for your time. I followed your instructions and still getting the same ACPI error, no pointer back to namespace when booting with a Ubuntu 18.04 live usb.

Comment: Yes, but you couldn't boot to the Live USB before, correct? Now you can, correct? I'm not so worried about the ACPI errors, yet, as they're probably bad BIOS errors. Confirm my first two comments and I'll tell you the next steps.

Comment: @heynnema I was able to boot into live usb with kernel parameter acpi=off. This same behavior happened now and I can get into the desktop with this parameter. i added dmesg and journalctl logs from the last session in EDIT4 now one minute ago. Regarding the memory test, yes it was the Dell diagnostic test which ran from the Bios, it tested everything including memory and all hard disks, this test took 4 hours, all tests passed.

Comment: You removed the two SSD's, but not the HDD, correct? I'm looking to boot the Live USB without the use of acpi=off. Can you remove the HDD and retest? Report back.

Comment: @heynnema I also removed the HDD with the two SSDs. Without acpi=off I can't boot. It gives me the acpi error mentioned before.

Comment: One desperate last attempt... reset the power manager... disconnect the internal battery... either by removing a removable battery, or disconnecting the internal battery cable. Disconnect the AC power. Without battery or AC, hold down the power button for about 15 seconds. Without reconnecting the battery, plug in the AC power and see if you can boot the Live USB without acpi=off. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Plugged out the battery, with power disconnected hold power button longer than 15 sec. Then plugged in charger, still same error with live usb.

Comment: @heynnema Also tested with another usb stick. Same error

Comment: OK, let me be clear... when you say "same error with Live USB", are you talking about the acpi errors, or the fact that you seem to need acpi=off?

Comment: I'm not adding the acpi=off parameter per your request. I am talking about the actual acpi errors, which are shown in the screenshot at step 5 in my initial post.

Comment: @heynnema As mentioned before. I am able to boot when adding the acpi=off parameter. But I am not doing that now.

Comment: The second image in step 5 shows NCQ errors on ata2.00, which is probably the new Samsung SSD. That may be taken care of with a firmware check/update, or adding a kernel parameter (libata.force=noncq) in the boot code. So let me ask another clarification question... When booting from the Live USB, it's NEVER booted without requiring the acpi=off, correct?

Comment: @heynnema Correct, it has never booted without requiring acpi=off. (Well at least since Sunday, since these problems appeared, before that everything was working fine). I can make another photo of the error.

Comment: @heynnema Added photo of current errors.

Comment: At this point, I'd have to say it's a hardware problem (motherboard) but I can't 100% prove it. I'd reinstall the stock SSD and HDD, ie: put it back to standard Dell configuration, and then call Dell. They'll probably only talk about Windows, unless it came with Ubuntu installed... so try and get a bootable Windows, if you can. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Alright, well thanks a lot for helping. Windows does work though, so what will I tell them to fix?

Comment: Oh, maybe I forgot that Windows works. In that case, create a Ubuntu Live 19.10 USB and boot to it without acpi=off, and see if there's anything different. Report back.

Comment: @heynnema Ubuntu 19.10 same error. Also something worth noting is that each time I install windows 10, I get two random freezes after it has been installed, after that it seems to run fine.

Comment: I read back, and indeed you said Windows had freezes, or wouldn't boot. That's what I would say to the Dell folks.

Comment: @heynnema wirh Ubuntu 19.10 acpi=off I get a kernel panic, see my last edit. Regarding the freezes it only seems to happen two or three times after installation. So they might not be able to reproduce the error?

Comment: I thought that we had disconnected all USB devices, no?

Comment: @heynnema Ok yes I disconnected everything except usb, because how else can I boot ubuntu from a live usb?

Comment: But besides the Live USB, is there any other USB device/hub still connected?

Comment: @heynnema No there are no other devices. Only the charger, utp cable and ubuntu live usb stick

Comment: OK, then we go back to, call Dell, and tell them the story using the Windows examples, and the diag test info, and see what they say. Sorry I can't help more :-(

Comment: @heynnema All right will do. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please do keep me posted, ok? Inquiring minds want to know :-)

Comment: @heynnema yes will do :)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

1. Clean or get the laptop cleaned (you would be surprised how much goes wrong with laptops and how frequently it is due to overheating).
2. As per the comments, try one RAM stick then the other, reseating them carefully, maybe watch a video on how to do that.
3. Create a Live-USB and see if you can boot an operating system off that to isolate if you have a hard drive problem or not and whether it can boot. ['Dohs](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0) or ['Nix](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 1. I did a quick clean, hut there wasnt much dust. 2. There is only one RAM stick, I reseated it. 3. Booting from live USB doesnt work either. With apci=off it did work. But as of now that also stopped working.

Comment: UEFI toggle? (123 - required characters.)

Comment: I also tried installing with legacy mode.

Comment: Sounded like something was going very wrong with the hardware, either the motherboard, bios or CPU. Did you try re-seating your CPU and RAM?